# Highcharts shared tooltip positioning if single value only

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, tooltip

If you see the example below, when you hover on the points, the tooltip will be to the left of the point, except when you hover on the month of 'June', where there is only a single value.

Im trying to get the tooltip to show in the same position when i hover on a point with multiple values on a single point, and also when i hover on a point with just 1 value available. (this is a shared tooltip).

Any idea how i can make the single value tooltip behave the same way as the others?

http://jsfiddle.net/2paj7L0h/ or snippet below:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
     connectNulls: true
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, null, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: You should be able to use tooltip.positioner for positioning your tooltip correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/2paj7L0h/1/

Comment: You can also disable shared, use formatter and loop inside to find all points from the same x. As a result you will keep position and all points in single popup.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński oooh yes thats what im looking for. although now the tooltip on edges will actually go out of the window. but i'll take it from here. thanks!

Comment: I am happy to hear that my example worked for you. Improved version of code that should meet your requiremets: http://jsfiddle.net/2paj7L0h/2/ If this example is ok for you I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński yeah sure please go ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in my comment, you should be able to use tooltip.positioner for positioning your tooltip near your points:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

```
  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true,
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
      var x;
      if (point.plotX - labelWidth / 2 > 0) {
        x = point.plotX - labelWidth / 2;
      } else {
        x = 0
      }
      return {
        x: x,
        y: point.plotY
      }
    },
    shape: 'square'
  },
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2paj7L0h/2/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you put a `null` value in the month of June of the second data array, if you put the correct value, the month will match correctly

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
     connectNulls: true
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: no, i guess i didnt explain it well. Thats actually my point. if one of the points has no value / null, i still want the tooltip to be positioned where it usually is

Comment: @wsgg ok, but if you put null, you can't show the value as the others, you might calculate wich value goes in the place you put null in order to the value can be showed

Comment: ah sorry, im not actually trying to show the null value. 
im just trying to get the tooltip to show in the same position